# IntegrityError column email is not unique

Tags: python, django

I am working on my Checkout view with regular/guest user but getting hard time to come around the integrity error. Idea is to let guest users register with email only to checkout and I need to set the user email unique.

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class UserCheckout(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User=get_user_model()
class GuestCheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Verify Email')
    def clean_email2(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        email2 = self.cleaned_data.get("email2")
        if email == email2:
            user_exists = User.objects.filter(email=email).count()
            if user_exists != 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError("User already exists. Please login instead")
            return email2
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please confirm emails addresses are the same.")
```

In my cart views this is how I've rendered my form.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            user_checkout = UserCheckout.objects.create(email=email)
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

I've registered the model with admin and in admin it shows the error for duplication perfectly fine but from frontend I am getting error below:

```
    IntegrityError at /checkout/
column email is not unique
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/checkout/
Django Version: 1.8.13
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
column email is not unique
Exception Location: C:\Users\Ali\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 318
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Ali\ecomm\Scripts\python.EXE
Python Version: 2.7.9
```

Comment: This is exactly the same question as [Django IntegrityError email is not unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162235/django-integrityerror-email-is-not-unique)