# Django IntegrityError email is not unique

Tags: python, django

I am working on my Checkout view with regular/guest user but getting hard time to come around the integrity error. Idea is to let guest users register with email only to checkout and I need to set the user email unique.

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class UserCheckout(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User=get_user_model()
class GuestCheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Verify Email')
    def clean_email2(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        email2 = self.cleaned_data.get("email2")
        if email == email2:
            user_exists = User.objects.filter(email=email).count()
            if user_exists != 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError("User already exists. Please login instead")
            return email2
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please confirm emails addresses are the same.")
```

In my cart views this is how I've rendered my form.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            user_checkout = UserCheckout.objects.create(email=email)
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

I've registered the model with admin and in admin it shows the error for duplication perfectly fine but from frontend I am getting error below:

```
IntegrityError at /checkout/
column email is not unique
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/checkout/
Django Version: 1.8.13
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
column email is not unique
Exception Location: C:\Users\Ali\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 318
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Ali\ecomm\Scripts\python.EXE
Python Version: 2.7.9
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your form is valid when it should not and it results in an `IntegrityError`?

Comment: All I intend to do is that if user already exists it should pop up message to login instead of registering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create every time when a checkout occurs an new `UserCheckout`. And in all these entries it is only allowed that every email exists only once.

I don't think you want this. Because if a guest orders two times it isn't allowed because his email is already in the DB. And that's why you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

The `clean_<fieldname>` methods of a `Form` are used to perform validation relative to single field. If you need validation with access to multiple fields, use the `clean` method. Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/) on form validation for a thorough explanation.

That would give:

```
class GuestCheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Verify Email')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please confirm emails addresses are the same.")
        return email

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(GuestCheckoutForm, self).clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        email2 = cleaned_data.get('email2')

        if email and email2 and email != email2:
            self.add_error('email2', forms.ValidationError('Please confirm emails addresses are the same.'))
```

**EDIT:** I believe I found out why you got an `IntegrityError`:
You are validation that no `User` with the given email is in the database, you should also be validating that no other `UserCheckout` with the given email is in the database. Replace `if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():` by `if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() or UserCheckout.objects.filter(email=email).exists():`

Comment: Its not letting me call super() in python 2.7. Secondly in last line ValidationError is not resolvable. It shows error. super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: Same error as posted in question. Nothing changed. But I got your point. However this gave me an idea to catch and alter integrity error as far as logic is clean. Do you think that's a better idea?

Comment: I think that is a solution, but an ugly one, you clearly have a bug somewhere that you will be hiding and that may bite you later on. P.-S. Have you seen my edit?

Comment: Yes I've implemented it but same result. Also see the error again as it is coming from the db. Like the way I've set up my models and then logic upon those models is not matching up.

Comment: your solution worked for me partially but I also had to go to my view in post and use "get_or_create" instead of "create". Thanks for help.